# Using Java Arrays to get min & max

Tags: java, arrays, max, min

thank you for your help.

Here is the assignment:

> Computer Technology Instructor has a small class of 10 students. The instructor evaluates the performance of students in the class by administering 2 midterm tests and a Final Exam.
>   Write  a  program  that  prompts the instructor to enter the  10 grades of midterm 1  and  store  these  numbers  in  an  array.  Next  prompt for the 10 grades of midterm 2 and store these numbers in a different array.  Next  prompt  for  the  10  grades  of  the Final  Exam  and  store  these  in  a  different  array.  Next  add  midterm1  to  midterm2  to  Final  and  store  the  totals  in  a  different  array.  **Next,  scan  the  array  that  has  the  totals  and  identify  the  minimum  grade  and  maximum grade.  Inform  the  instructor  of  the  minimum  grade and maximum grade.**

The two bold phrases are where I am having problems. Everything works except for the minimum grade and maximum grade. Here is what it tells me, after I've only entered numbers between 65 and 100:

> The highest test score is: 276 The lowest test score is: 249

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// Prompt for the 1st mid term
    int [] midTerm1 = new int[10];
    int [] midTerm2 = new int[10];
    int [] finalExam = new int[10];
    int [] grades = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < midTerm1.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the 10 Mid Term 1 grades: ");
        midTerm1[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    // Prompt for the 2nd mid term


    for (int i = 0; i < midTerm2.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the 10 Mid Term 2 grades: ");
        midTerm2[i] = input.nextInt();
    }


    // Prompt for Final grades


    for (int i = 0; i < finalExam.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter a Final Exam grade: ");
        finalExam[i] = input.nextInt();
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
        grades[i] = (midTerm1[i] + midTerm2[i] + finalExam[i]);
    }

    int minGrade = grades[0];
    int maxGrade = grades[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)

    {
    if (minGrade > grades[i])
      minGrade = grades[i];
    if (maxGrade < grades[i])
      maxGrade = grades[i];

    }


    System.out.print("The highest test score is: " + maxGrade);
    System.out.print("The lowest test score is: " + minGrade);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

```
grades[i] = (midTerm1[i] + midTerm2[i] + finalExam[i]);
```

Your code may in fact be correct. Since you're adding your three test scores together, expect that the grade will be not between 65 and 100 but rather between 195 and 300.

If you want a number between 65 and 100, this needs to be divided by 3:

```
grades[i] = (midTerm1[i] + midTerm2[i] + finalExam[i]) / 3;
```

or else find some other way to *normalize* the grades. For instance, if the final is 50% of the grade then you could have:

```
grades[i] = (25 * midTerm1[i] + 25 * midTerm2[i] + 50 * finalExam[i]) / 100;
```

But again your current solution may in fact be the correct one.

Comment: Based on the instructions, it doesn't seem like the min and max should be between 65 and 100. It doesn't seem like it wanted them to be averaged or weighted in any way it just wanted the total.

Comment: @AlliK: thanks and yep, I agree, that's why I edited my answer and added the last current line.

Comment: I think @Christf doesn't realize the code is correct though based on the instructions so I was just trying to point that out. The code for min and max is right.

Comment: Well, I feel slightly embarrassed. I should have read more carefully since it says "scan the array THAT HAS THE TOTALS" Thanks!